# delete function for json.stringify + var

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have a bunch of images that are showing up in a gallery.
From a json file.

each `<img>` has an id,
On click a jquery script excutes that takes the id
and passes it back through a ajax to php script that should remove that image from the json.

Here is the code I have:

```html
  function deletebtn(){

    $(".delete-button").click(function(event) {

        var deleteme = event.target.id;
        $("#"+ deleteme).remove();



          var jsondelete = "http://localhost/wordpress/api/json/gallery.json";
          $.getJSON( jsondelete, {
            format: "json"
          })
            .done(function( data ) {
               delete data.images.+deleteme;

               var data = JSON.stringify(data);
               $( "#json_delete" ).html(data);
               var brick = $( "#json_delete" ).html();
               $.ajax({
                   url: 'http://localhost/gallery/deletejson.php',
                   method: 'POST',
                   data: {
                     "json": brick,
                   },
                   success: function(result) {
                   console.log("SAVED JSON");
                 },
                   error: function(result) {
                   alert("DID NOT SAVE JSON");
                   }
               });
            });


    });

}
```

The issue im having is
I cant use this

```html
delete data.images.+deleteme;
```

If turn this function into

```
delete data.images.img_177;
```

this works.
How ever im trying to pass the var $deleteme

```
var $deleteme = event.target.id;
```

which if you use alert or console log is

```
img_177
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Use `[]` notation .... `delete data.images[deleteme];`

Comment: Note, the variable name is declared as `$deleteme`, not `deleteme`

Comment: i just noticed that, both your answers fixed my issue :) thanks!